# CKAN Upload File to Dataset via Postman (Manual HTTP Requests)

Tags: rest, api, postman, ckan

I'm trying to upload a file into a CKAN dataset using the API's.
I eventually want to do that via .NET. For the moment, to understand how I want the request to look like, I am using Postman to simulate.

So far I am unable to get it to work correctly. Can anyone please guide me on how the request should look like?

As I understood from the [API guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/filestore.html#filestore-api), it should look like this:
[image: Postman CKAN request]

However this give the error message displayed in the screenshot:
"Bad request - JSON Error: Invalid request. Please use POST method for your request". The dataset with that name already exists. The provided API key is correct and used successfully in another request (creating the dataset).

Obviously the request type is already POST.

I'm not sure what's wrong. Can someone advise please?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the trailing `/` from the url, that may be causing a redirect to get without trailing `/` and hence the error about using `POST` method. That's my hunch

Comment: What? WHAT?! I spent a week running around everywhere because of a slash?! Please post that as the answer so that I can accept it and give you the bounty. I owe you a beer sir!

Comment: Let me know your country, I am in India, when we both are in same country, will have beer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the trailing `/` from the url, that may be causing a redirect to a `GET` without trailing `/` and hence the error about using `POST` method

Comment: That was actually it! Once I removed the slash it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error with `organization_create` using CKAN 2.8.2.

Same exact request in Postman (and the request in a program I wrote) work fine in another CKAN instance running 2.8.3.

It sort of sounds like they fixed this in 2.8.3 but I can't say since the public CKAN changelog only goes to 2.8.2.